# How to count entries specifically matching another row in join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to make an SQL query that shows the number of comments on each post. The problem is, the query i have been trying to add to already has a LEFT JOIN. So far i have succeeded on making it show a post (although a wrong one) and total amount of comments in the entire table with the following query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  Count(tbl_comments.comm_id) as CommentCount
 FROM
  tbl_posts 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_posts.author = tbl_users.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_comments ON tbl_posts.post_id = tbl_comments.comm_id 
 WHERE
  tbl_users.role >= 3
 ORDER BY
  tbl_posts.post_time DESC
 LIMIT
  1
```

With the Count part commented the query returns the most recent post. Otherwise it returns the first post in the database, and a total amount of comments in the whole table. How would i go about making it show the correct (latest) post and the comments made only on that post? The comment table has a "parent" field, where i am storing the id of the post that the comment is posted on, but i can't figure out where in the query to specify that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why you need the first `LEFT JOIN` can you have posts without author?  You can have post without comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of comment on each post. you need `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  tbl_posts.post_id,
  Count(tbl_comments.comm_id) as CommentCount
 FROM
  tbl_posts 
  INNER JOIN tbl_users 
     ON tbl_posts.author = tbl_users.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_comments 
     ON tbl_posts.post_id = tbl_comments.comm_id 
 WHERE
  tbl_users.role >= 3
 GROUP BY tbl_posts.post_id
```

NOTE: This Join condition looks weird to me

```
ON tbl_posts.post_id = tbl_comments.comm_id
```

should be:

```
ON tbl_posts.post_id = tbl_comments.post_id
```

My guess `comm_id` is the PK on comments not the FK.

Comment: Yep, that did it, thanks! You were right, i used the wrong field in the join too. Also sorry for the incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `group_by` from `post.id`  and then do a `count(tbl.comments.id)` on each of the post. That way you can get the distinct count of comments associated with a single post for each post.